# Writing for loop for focal statistics?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, iterator

Im trying to run Focal statistics on a list of parameters, where the radius changes for each input parameter and then save the resultant DTM with the radius attached in the name. I can do this for one file, however trying to implement this within a for loop is I get the error NbrVircle object does not support item assignment. My code is below.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "D:/Kieran"

Parameters=[50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400]
# Set local variables
inRaster = "D:/temp/DTM.asc"
    # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

for i in Parameters:
    neighborhood[i] = NbrCircle(i, "CELL")
    # Execute FocalStatistics
    outFocalStatistics[i] = FocalStatistics(inRaster, neighborhood, "MEAN","")
    # Save the output
    outFocalStatistics.save("D:/temp/DTM"+[i]+".asc")
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking this code is almost there, and the only problem might be the one you have have already identified as the source of the `does not support item assignment` error. While the item-wise assignment strategy is fancy and rather cool, if I were in a similar situation I would sort of simplify or dumb-down the code surrounding the error. Hopefully the following will dodge the error:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "D:/Kieran"

Parameters=[50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400]
# Set local variables
inRaster = "D:/temp/DTM.asc"
    # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

for i in Parameters:
    current_neighborhood = NbrCircle(i, "CELL")
    # Execute FocalStatistics
    outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(inRaster, current_neighborhood, "MEAN","")
    # Save the output
    outFocalStatistics.save("D:/temp/DTM"+ str(i) +".asc")
    del outFocalStatistics # ...delete this object, just in case...
    del current_neighborhood # ...delete this object, just in case...
```

Best Luck with this!

Comment: This works super. Thanks very much. I had to change `".asc"` to`".tif"` as .asc is not supported